# HTML or CSS navigation bar issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I have created a navigation bar that has an underline when hovered and also when it is active. I also have a line spanning the page. When the cursor is hovered over the list, the 4px line appears under the word but it also pushed the line spanning the page down by 4 pixels. Can someone help please.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="new1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="ddmenu">
        <div class="menu-icon"></div>
        <ul>
            <li class='top-heading'><a href='#'><span>New in</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='top-heading'><a href='#'><span>Homeware</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='top-heading'><a href='#'><span>Decorating</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='top-heading'><a href='#'><span>DIY</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='top-heading'><a href='#'><span>Furniture</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='top-heading'><a href='#'><span>Bathroom</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='top-heading'><a href='#'><span>Garden</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='top-heading'><a href='#'><span>Offers</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS

```
#ddmenu {
  zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0px 0;
}
#ddmenu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#ddmenu:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#ddmenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEBEB;
  border-top: 1px solid #EAEBEB;
  zoom: 1;
}
#ddmenu ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#ddmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#ddmenu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#ddmenu li a {
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 1px 50px 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#ddmenu li:hover, #ddmenu .active {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #EAEBEB;
  colour: #000
}
#ddmenu .active a {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify your HTML+CSS a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a border you're increasing the height of the element so naturally it affects items below it.

Without a set height the optimal solution is to have the border already there but **transparent** and just change the color on `hover`.

```
#ddmenu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom:4px solid transparent;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4cLt2t3k/4/)

Note: Just a suggestion but you have a *lot* of padding on the links there. As you can see it in the doesn't look quite so nice at smaller viewports...you might want to look into that.

Comment: You're my new best friend :D

Comment: You are very welcome. If this answer helped you might wish to upvote or mark as the accepted answer when time allows.

Comment: I did try but my rep isn't hight enough yet :(

Comment: No problem. You'll get there.

Comment: You can always accept an answer – regardless of your reputation.